# listview gets wrong display order

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a `ListView` to display category items, below this, I have a control menu writen in a LinerLayout, and, also an `EditText` and go Button at the top of this app.

Everything is fine at the first running time. however, when I click the `EditText` for input, the menu bar is pulled up since the keyboard appear. Now, the order of the `ListView` has been changed.

example:
at beginning: 1 Meeting 2 Event 3 Schedule 4 Reminder
Later keyboard shows and everything pulled up: 1 Schedule 2 Reminder 3 Meeting 4 Event.

I also find that this problem will only happen when there is no enough space to keep showing the whole `ListView`.

I can't solve this problem after I searched for long time on the internet.

This is my layout and my List Apdater

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout ...>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/items"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/widget53"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/widget39"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

            <ImageButton ../>

            <ImageButton ../>

            <ImageButton ../>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/widget53"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

            <Button ../>

            <EditText .. />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
//Write item on the screen
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.items);
            lv.setAdapter(indexadapter.getAdapter());
            lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(ItemClick);
//My list Adapter generate rows base on mData from database
    CategoryHolder CategoryHolder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            //getting view format
            CategoryHolder = new CategoryHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.categoryshow, null);
            CategoryHolder.category=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.indexcategory);
        //setting tag for reuse;
            convertView.setTag(CategoryHolder);
        //setting text for each item;
        CategoryHolder.category.setText((String)mData.get(position).get("CATEGORY"));
        }else{
            CategoryHolder = (CategoryHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
```

Comment: show us the some code, (xml layout and your `onCreate()`)

Comment: sounds like you don't use the list view for scrolling but just to display all of your items (am i right?) if so why do you use listview?

Comment: It solved by dldnh's answer. But I still don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your AndroidManifest.xml file, in your <activity...> definition, include `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` like so:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ClassName"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
    ...
</activity>
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining how exactly this solved the issue? For me it just looks like a magical solution rather than a logical one. Thanks!

Comment: This is why this works...The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing. This is generally less desirable than resizing, because the user may need to close the soft keyboard to get at and interact with obscured parts of the window.

source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

Answer (score 0):

When you use the convertView of the getView() method in your listadapter, you need to set the text for every view again. To fully understand how listviews are working and how the views are recycled you should watch these video form the google I/O 2010 http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html